# How to get eslint-plugin-import to recognise external deps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, eslint

I have installed `eslint-plugin-import` but am struggling to configure it

I have this basic config

```
  "import/order": [
      "error",
      {
        "groups": ["builtin", "external", "internal"],
        "pathGroups": [
          {
            "pattern": "react",
            "group": "external",
            "position": "before"
          },
        ],
        "pathGroupsExcludedImportTypes": ["react"],
        "newlines-between": "always",
        "alphabetize": {
          "order": "asc",
          "caseInsensitive": true
        }
      }
    ]
```

It is complaining here:

```
import { css } from "emotion"
// others imports

import { something } from "app/constants"
```

it says `emotion import should occur after import of app/consts` but it definitely shouldn't as `emotion` is clearly external and `app/constants` is clearly internal. do I need to configure this somehow?